# There is only 728Mb free space in my Ubuntu One folder?

Tags: ubuntu-one

I signed up for Ubuntu One, it says that I will get 5GB free storage space, but on my PC the Ubuntu One folder is only 728Mb.

What is happening here?

Comment: Where are you getting this free space number from?  Might this be the amount of free space on your local disk instead?

Comment: Alternately, are you seeing the total consumed space in the folder?

Comment: Can you give us a screenshot?

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu One stores files on your disk, and does not operate as a networked drive. The "free space" reading you see in the file manager is the amount of free space available for the disk partition on which that directory exists. Your `$HOME` and `$HOME/Ubuntu One` folders should both show the same amount of space available, when looking in the file manager.